# How to determine the amount of pixel of an given ROI?

Tags: python, jython, imagej

I wrote a small program to give me certain information about ROIs I found by using "Analyze Particles...". Unfortunatly I need information about the amount of pixel per ROI. When I am not using "Set Scale" prior to this plugin I will maybe get the amount of pixels by the area output. But for further calculating prior "Set Scale" is needed. Is there a possibility to extract the amount of pixels per ROI after using "Analyze Particles...". I only found this possibility in java (nearly not readable for me as a beginner in python) http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/download/Calculate_Mean.java and its seems to be very computationally intensive. Thanking you in advance.

```
import math

row = 0

IJ.run("Set Measurements...", "area centroid perimeter shape feret's area_fraction   redirect=None decimal=6")
IJ.run("Analyze Particles...")
rt = ResultsTable.getResultsTable()

for roi in RoiManager.getInstance().getRoisAsArray():
  a = rt.getValue("Feret", row)
  b = rt.getValue("MinFeret", row)
  nu= 1
  L = 1
  p = 1
  sapf = (math.pi/4) * (1/(nu*L)) * math.pow(a, 3) * math.pow(b, 3) / (math.pow(a, 2) + math.pow(a, 2))*p
  rt.setValue("ROI no.", row, row + 1)
  rt.setValue("Sapflow", row, sapf)
  row = row + 1
rt.show("Results")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(In general, questions that are more related to ImageJ internals rather than programming languages should be addressed to the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/list.html). This will make sure your question will be read by most expert users and developers of ImageJ, not only by a couple of *stackoverflow.com* enthusiasts.)

1. You can use the [calibration](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/index.html?ij/measure/Calibration.html) information to calculate back the pixel count from the area:

   > Pixel count = Total Area / Pixel area
2. You can use the [`ImageStatistics.getStatistics()`](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/index.html?ij/process/ImageStatistics.html) method to get its `pixelCount` value for the current ROI.

   Here's how your code looks after the addition of a few lines:

   ```
   import math

   row = 0

   IJ.run("Set Measurements...", "area centroid perimeter shape feret's area_fraction   redirect=None decimal=6")
   IJ.run("Analyze Particles...")
   rt = ResultsTable.getResultsTable()

   imp = IJ.getImage()
   ip = imp.getProcessor()

   for roi in RoiManager.getInstance().getRoisAsArray():
     a = rt.getValue("Feret", row)
     b = rt.getValue("MinFeret", row)
     nu= 1
     L = 1
     p = 1
     sapf = (math.pi/4) * (1/(nu*L)) * math.pow(a, 3) * math.pow(b, 3) / (math.pow(a, 2) + math.pow(a, 2))*p
     rt.setValue("ROI no.", row, row + 1)
     rt.setValue("Sapflow", row, sapf)

     ip.setRoi(roi)
     stats = ImageStatistics.getStatistics(ip, Measurements.AREA, None)
     rt.setValue("Pixel count", row, stats.pixelCount)

     row = row + 1
   rt.show("Results")
   ```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you again, for further questions regarding ImageJ issues I will use the ImageJ mailing list.